# Predicate in array

Tags: iphone

I have an array which contains lots of info like lat,lon,city name etc.But all this info stored by class object.

```
("<GetCityList: 0x1fd334d0>",
"<GetCityList: 0x1fd33560>",
"<GetCityList: 0x1fd33310>",)
```

my array is looking like this.if i want city name then first i create GetCityList object and then object.cityName.
Now i have to search lat and lon by comparing cityName.so how can i do,because it consumes too much time?can i use predicate ?how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let say you have an array of cityList and want to Filter this by city name you can do

```
NSPredicate *cityNamePredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"cityName contains[c] %@", @"cityName"]
NSArray *filteredCityList = [cityList filteredArrayUsingPredicate:cityNamePredicate];
```

Above filteredCityList will be your required filtered array whatever you passed in parameter. Here [cd] means case and diatric insensitive

You can refer [this tutorial](http://blog.mugunthkumar.com/coding/iphone-tutorial-uisearchdisplaycontroller-with-nspredicate/) for further exploring NSPredicate.

Answer (score 0):

Example:

```
self.data = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                         [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"To Airport",@"TO/AIR", nil] forKeys:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:kName,kCode, nil]],
                         [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Point-to-Point",@"PTP", nil] forKeys:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:kName,kCode, nil]],[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"From Airport",@"FR/AIR", nil] forKeys:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:kName,kCode, nil]], nil];

NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(name CONTAINS[cd]  %@)",searchText];
self.searchableData = [self.data filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
```

Based on this you can replace name with cityName.

Answer (score 0):

Use it in this way also:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"cityName contains %@", @"cityNamehere"]

NSMutableArray *filtered = [cityListArray filterUsingPredicate:predicate];
```